# Rust: implement trait for the associated type

Tags: rust, lifetime, associated-types, generic-associated-types

In the snippet below (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5babd9991122c756e7afaa76da0b32f3)

```rust
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]
#![feature(marker_trait_attr)]

// StrSpan is opaque and imported from nom_locate
struct StrSpan<'a>(&'a str);

pub trait LifetimizedExt {
    type Lifetimized<'a>;
}

impl<T> LifetimizedExt for Option<T>
where
    T: LifetimizedExt
{
    type Lifetimized<'a> = Option<T::Lifetimized<'a>>;
}

impl<'a,T> LifetimizedExt for &'a T
where
    T: 'static + ?Sized
{
    type Lifetimized<'b> = &'b T;
}

impl<'a,T> LifetimizedExt for &'a mut T
where
    T: 'static + ?Sized
{
    type Lifetimized<'b> = &'b mut T;
}

#[marker]
pub trait ParsableInput: LifetimizedExt {}

impl<'a> ParsableInput for &'a str {}
impl<'a> ParsableInput for StrSpan<'a> {}

impl<'a,I> ParsableInput for I::Lifetimized<'a>
where
    I: ParsableInput
{}
```

specifically in

```rust
impl<'a,I> ParsableInput for I::Lifetimized<'a>
where
    I: ParsableInput
{}
```

`I` is unconstrained.

According to https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0207,

> Any type parameter of an impl must meet at least one of the following criteria:
>
> - it appears in the implementing type of the impl, e.g. impl Foo
>   for a trait impl,
> - it appears in the implemented trait, e.g. impl SomeTrait > for Foo
> - it is bound as an associated type, e.g. impl<T, U> SomeTrait for T where T: AnotherTrait<AssocType=U>

How do I rewrite the original snippet?

I always want to use `ParsableInput` trait to infer that `I::Lifetimized<'a>` is `ParsableInput` for any lifetime `'a`. Is it possible?

## Requested addition.

The reasons why such behavior is desired are that

1. It's just stating the important fact about the concerned types
2. [Nom combinators](https://github.com/Geal/nom/blob/main/doc/choosing_a_combinator.md) require specific type signatures for functions to be used as their arguments.

They are generic as well. For example, [line_ending](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/character/complete/fn.line_ending.html). It requires `T: InputIter + InputLength`.

Without generic associated types, there will be too much repetition, and even one small combinatorial explosion (NxM implementations).

```rust
pub trait Parse<'a,I>: Sized
where
    I: ParsableInput,
    Self: LifetimizedExt<Lifetimized<'a> = Self>
{
    /// Returns [`Result<P,E>`] where any [`Ok(p)`] is a pair `(i,val)`, s.t.
    /// * `i` is the remaining input after parsing
    /// * `val` is the parsed value
    fn parse<'b, 'c>(i: I::Lifetimized<'b>) -> IResult<I::Lifetimized<'c>, Self::Lifetimized<'a>>
    where
        'b: 'c,
        'b: 'a;
}
```

## Addition #2: "Why `LifetimizedExt` exists"

Its associated generic type `Lifetimized` is the reification of the class of types equivalent to `Self` up to lifetime. I needed to make implementations of `Parse::parse` for `(&'b str,&'c str)` and for `(StrSpan<'b>,StrSpan<'c>)` (modulo other details). Theoretically, I could supply a pair-type-argument but (sic) `parse` wouldn't be generic.

**Note**: Now I realize that it could be generic if the constructed triple `(&'a str,&'b str,&'c str)` satisfied some trait but it would make things even more complicated.

## Addition #3: "Why was genericity in Parse::parse needed"

There also was `map_parsed_val` function,

```rust
// Proper declaration and implementation requires GATs

use nom::IResult;

pub trait MapParsedValInTuple<'a, T>
where
    for<'c> T: super::Parse<'a,&'c str>,
{
    fn map_parsed_val<'b, U, F: FnOnce(T) -> U>(self, f: F) -> (&'b str, U)
    where
        'a: 'b;
}

impl<'a, T> MapParsedValInTuple<'a, T> for (&'a str, T)
where
    for<'c> T: super::Parse<'a,&'c str>,
{
    fn map_parsed_val<'b, U, F: FnOnce(T) -> U>(self, f: F) -> (&'b str, U)
    where
        'a: 'b,
    {
        let (remaining_input,parsed_val) = (self.0, self.1);
        (remaining_input, f(parsed_val))
    }
}

pub trait MapParsedValInResult<'a, T> {
    fn map_parsed_val<'b, U, F: FnOnce(T) -> U>(self, f: F) -> IResult<&'b str, U>
    where
        'a: 'b;
}

impl<'a, T> MapParsedValInResult<'a, T> for IResult<&'a str, T> {
    fn map_parsed_val<'b, U, F: FnOnce(T) -> U>(self, f: F) -> IResult<&'b str, U>
    where
        'a: 'b,
    {
        self.map(|(i, parsed_val)| (i, f(parsed_val)))
    }
}
```

I haven't rewritten it yet but you can see that GATs would be nifty here. Also, you can notice that it deals only with types whose type-parameter for `Parse` is `&str`. With the addition of `StrSpan`, in this place too would happen combinatorial explosion. It's also important to note that it ends life of the parsed value while keeping the lifetime of the remaining input intact. How long they will live, how the function will be used, is unknown (and irrelevant as long as genericity in the method is there). It also makes sense that this method should be generic.

Comment: You can't. But it looks like XY problem.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I made an addition that also explains why such behavior is desired. And thank you for your comment!

Comment: @DmitriiDemenev the Rust solution would be to instead require that `ParsableInput::Lifetimized` implements `ParsableInput` and leave the decision of how `ParsableInput` be implemented up to those implementing the trait. You can add trait requirements by saying `type Lifetimized<'a>: ParsableInput;`.

Comment: `LifetimizedExt` seems like a bit of a contradiction in of itself. In order to fix this code you may need to help explain why it is exists in the first place. From what I can tell, `Lifetimized` always appears to be `Self`, but with a different lifetime. However, this does not make much sense because we only constrain lifetimes by ensuring they meet a minimum threshold. The upper bound on a type's lifetime is considered part of the type already though so any check or constraint using `T::Lifetimized<'a>` could instead be done by enforcing `T: 'a`.

Comment: @Locke I'm still processing your first comment above but `LifetimizedExt` exists so that there's a possibility to refer to the identical types with different lifetimes. Basically, I'm trying to express that some methods, including but not limited to Parse::parse,  reference (or, in the degenerate case, ignore) the data in the arguments and return data that can live different time.

Comment: The difference in lifetimes can come, for example, from `map_parsed_val` function that essentially ends life of the parsed value and creates another value from its contents.

Comment: @Locke I provided further explanation of reason for existence of `LifetimizedExt`

Comment: Honestly, it currently looks like an implementational constraint on the language rather than "you should it somehow else because other ways are standard/better".